# Accessing vector elements in R Programing

Tags: r

## Accessing vector elements using 0/1 indexing.

```
t <- c("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thurs","Fri","Sat")
y <- t[c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1)]
print(y)

[1] "Sun"
```

Could not follow why answer is Sunday rather than Saturday. All elements have been coded 0 whilst the 7th is coded 1 hence I expected the 7th day of the week Saturday to be the answer

Similarly
Adjusting the indexing as below

```
y <- t[c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)]
print(y)

[1] "Sun" "Sun" "Sun" "Sun" "Sun" "Sun" "Sun"
```

Answer continues to be Sun.

Could someone elaborate the logic for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using numeric indexing, the indices correspond to the positions of elements in the vector.

You will see that

```
> t[0]
character(0)

> t[1]
[1] "Sun"

> t[c(0, 1)]
[1] "Sun"
```

From you post, it seems you want to use index as a mask. In that case, you may need to use boolean values for indexing, which act like a switch, e.g., "on" and "off", to decide if the element in place should be selected, e.g.,

```
> t[c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1) > 0]
[1] "Tue" "Sat"
```

since

```
> c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1) > 0
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it is a numeric index i.e. binary.  In `R`, the indexing starts from 1 and therefore, 0 values are discarded, but the value at the end i.e. 1 extracts the element of 't' at the first position.  If we convert to logical it will work, it will extract the element that corresponds to `TRUE` value

```
t[as.logical(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1))]
#[1] "Sat"
```